# Difference in libpaths between Rstudio and Knitr with packrat

Tags: r, knitr, packrat

I have a RMD file. I can knit it with knitr from RStudio interface. But when I try to run a separate chunk in console I got errors:

`Error in library(bla) : there is no package called bla`

where `bla` is my homemade package. I haven't installed `bla` to my current project. I have packrat initialised and `bla` absent from packrat directories. So both ways should not work.

Call `.libPaths()` shows me

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/user/projdir/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.0" 
[2] "/home/user/projdir/packrat/lib-ext/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.0" 
[3] "/home/user/projdir/packrat/lib-R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.0"
```

I've added `.libPaths()` call to my document and got:

```
[1] "/home/user/Documents/projdir/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.0"
[2] "/home/user/Documents/projdir/packrat/lib-ext/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.0"   
[3] "/home/user/Documents/projdir/packrat/lib-R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.0"   
[4] "/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4"
[5] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[6] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[7] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Why the paths differ? And how can I force knitr to use packages only from packrat?

Comment: Something is weird.  5, 6, and 7 of the second answer are the standard Debian (and Ubuntu and other derivatives) setting you should also have in the first answer.   Now, I don't use `packrat` myself so I don't know what it does -- but all the default R behaviour (and then some) is explained in `help(Startup)`.  There are some env. vars. you can check.